# Why can't I emit event inside subscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript

Why is it not possible to emit an event inside an observable's subscribe?

Child component:

```
@Component({selector: 'child'})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() errors = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private someService: SomeService);

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errors.emit(123); // Works
    }

    someMethod() {
        this.someService.someFunction().subscribe(
            () => { ... }
            (errors) => { 
                console.log("Reached here successfully");
                this.errors.emit(errors); // Does not work
            } 
        )
    }
}
```

And the parent component:

```
@Component({selector: 'parent'})
export class ParentComponent {
    onErrors(errors) {
        console.log(errors);
    }
}
```

This is ParentComponent's html

```
<child (errors)="onErrors($event)"></child>
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work? I cn see not test code that confirms that proper callback is beeing called

Comment: Could you maybe post the whole `someMethod()` code?

Comment: also it would be good to know how you call `someMethod()`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you just pasted the code incorrectly but you are missing a comma (,) between the `success` and `catch` methods

```
@Component({selector: 'child'})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() errors = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private someService: SomeService);

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errors.emit(123); // Works
    }

    someMethod() {
        this.someService.someFunction().subscribe(
            () => { ... }, // <---- comma was missing here 
            (errors) => { 
                console.log("Reached here successfully");
                this.errors.emit(errors); // Does not work
            } 
        )
    }
}
```

Also, just to improve your code a bit, the new recommendation is to use the observer object:

```
.subscribe({
      next: (something) => {},
      error: (error) => {}, 
      closed : () => {},
      complete: () => {}
    })
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any solution on this please?

Comment: this.errors.emit(errors) --> this line does not triggers at all. Very strange !

Answer (score 0):

So for those coming here trying to find the answer. The only option here would be to use ViewChild to communicate your data with parent component. Or use and RXJS service but that might be an overkill. Sadly I do not know why event is not emitted when inside an observable subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and it turned out I was conditionally rendering the component that the event was in if there was an API request and when I made the request it removed the component thus not emitting an event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).