# Emitting an event inside an event

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, eventemitter

So I am trying to emit an event to my parent component from the child component.

I emit it when the valueChanges event triggers. This works only once and then not anymore.

Is this possible to do in Angular?

Emitting an event on new event trigger?

Might be connected to [Why can't I emit event inside subscribe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690611/why-cant-i-emit-event-inside-subscribe).

```
@Output('formChanged') formEmitter = new EventEmitter();
ngOnInit() {
    this.currencyConversionForm.valueChanges.subscribe((selectedValue: any) => {
      console.log('form value changed');
      console.log(selectedValue);
      this.formEmitter.emit(selectedValue);
    })
}

handleFormChanged(value: any) {
   console.log(value);
   his.amount = value.amount;
   this.baseCurrency = value.baseCurrencyForm;
   this.counterCurrency = value.counterCurrencyForm;
}
```

This works the first time when I call it, but not the second time.

Comment: Should work fine. Do child's `console.log`s run?

Comment: It runs only the first time and it logs it. But after that it doesnt work or log it. But if i remove the this.formEmitter.emit(selectedValue); it works as expected

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No. The console doesn't return any errors ...

Comment: This is how I am calling it "(formChanged)="handleFormChanged($event)">"

Comment: Actually, I think it works now. I move this.currencyConversionForm initialization together with valueChanges to ngOnInit life cycle hook.